# Angular Compile Error: NG6001: The class is listed in the declarations of the NgModule 'AppModule', but is not a directive, a component, or a pipe

Tags: angular, typescript

App fails to compile with error

> error NG6001: The class `NavigationMenuItemComponent` is listed in the declarations of the NgModule `AppModule`, but is not a directive, a component, or a pipe. Either remove it from the NgModule's declarations, or add an appropriate Angular decorator.

The error goes away when I remove the constructor with parameters. How can I resolve this whiles maintaining the constructor that has parameters, because I want to use to initialise a list of the component without having to call set methods for each member in the list

```
import {
    Component,
    OnInit
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-navigation-menu-item',
    templateUrl: './navigation-menu-item.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./navigation-menu-item.component.scss']
})
export class NavigationMenuItemComponent implements OnInit {
    static readonly ID_PREFIX: string = 'sidebar-menuitem-';
    static readonly ICON_CLASS_PREFIX: string = 'mdi mdi-';

    constructor(id: string, iconClass: string) {
        this._id = NavigationMenuItemComponent.ID_PREFIX + id;
        this._iconClass = NavigationMenuItemComponent.ICON_CLASS_PREFIX + iconClass;
    }
    //constructor() {}

    private _id: string;
    private _iconClass: string;

    get id() {
        return this._id;
    }

    get iconClass() {
        return this._iconClass;
    }

    set id(id: string) {
        this._id = NavigationMenuItemComponent.ID_PREFIX + id;
    }

    set iconClass(iconClass) {
        this._iconClass = NavigationMenuItemComponent.ID_PREFIX + iconClass;
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

Comment: What is your module file? seems the problems are there

Comment: In my case I had to restart `ng serve` to make it work! But another possibility is that you wrote `*ngIf` with a lowercase i like `*ngif`

Comment: For me it was: The wrongly marked components had an error in their .ts-file which VSC didn't show until I opened that file. After fixing the error the declaration worked without a flaw.

Comment: Just thought I'd add my solution (problem), I used two incompatible decorators; `@NgModule` and `@Component`.
Somehow this only now caused issues (during a big upgrade), but removing the `@NgModule` solved my issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose that it's happening, because Angular is designed to use component's constructor to work with Dependency Injection system which is based on classes and not primitives.

Basically, you **cannot** create your own component and provide it's constructor with desired props.

*Why*, because it would break Inversion of control principle, which leads to maintainability problems.

What you can do:

1. Use `@Input()` this decorator is specifically designed by Angular's dev team to provide component with values at run time. It doesn't matter if you will change them later. You may read more [here](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs#how-to-use-input) and [here](https://angular.io/api/core/Input)
2. If you need some kind of config to provide globally or at some level you could create your own `Injector` and provide it with `Token` you created so that component may consume. Some info could be found [here](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action#injectiontoken-objects)

Basically, you should be OK with 1st approach as it's clear what you are doing in your code and it's a common practice, meanwhile 2nd approach is more cumbersome and would better suit for usage in services.

---

### TL;DR

Use `@Input` as it's a common practice of passing down properties to children components.

Answer (score 57):

You have to run `npm install` when creating new components. Hot reload doesn't seem to be able to add the component.

Comment: Reexecuting `ng serve` did it for me.

Answer (score 25):

When you have multiple error-messages, this error message may show up first.
So **make sure to also check the other error messages**.

In my case I had a typo in the `tempalteURL` (another error message clearly expressed this: `NG2008: Could not find template file`)

Comment: I had a capital case letter in the templateURL instead of a small - it wasn't obvious and since it compiled on local it took me hours to figure out where the problem was.

Comment: Yes, fixing other issues solved for me

Comment: Yes, fixing the other, simpler error made this error go away

Comment: In retrospect, this bit of advice seems obvious, but: check to see if the class mentioned has an issue.  Mine had an invalid import statement at the top.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue. Removing OnInit in the declaration part as well as inside the class helped me. Because it initialized all data-bound properties of the directive.
Since this component could have been added in app.module.ts.

```
export class NavigationMenuItemComponent {
     ....
     ....
     set iconClass(iconClass) {
            this._iconClass = NavigationMenuItemComponent.ID_PREFIX + iconClass;
        }

        //ngOnInit(): void {}
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Add these lines in component:

```js
constructor() {};

ngOnInit(): void {};
```

I am also facing same issue but I think the error occurs because angular is no more treating it as complete component by adding contructor and `ngOnIt` have fixed issue.

Comment: Worked for me! 
In my case the trailing " ; " was missing after the constructor, adding `constructor() {};` fixed it

Answer (score 3):

check if the paths mentioned in 'templateUrl' and 'styleUrls' exsists,

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-navigation-menu-item',
    templateUrl: './navigation-menu-item.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./navigation-menu-item.component.scss']
})
```

in my case, this was the bug.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error message after I tried to move a component in another folder with Resharper in Visual Studio.
The issue was with one of the imports got messed up, namely:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewChild } from '@angular/core/core';
```

Fixed it like so:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
```

Comment: Thanks, that was my issue after doing a 'move' refactoring using ReShaper.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had renewed the component files.  But I missed to update `templateUrl` to new file name.  Once corrected the `templateUrl` file names, all started working fine.

This is strange but the error is same for multiple reasons so at times it is misleading!

Answer (score 2):

This also could happen due to invalid imports. For me,this happen due to `ViewEncapsulation` import

change

```
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/compiler';
```

to this

```
import {  Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
```

Answer (score 1):

Following worked for me.

There was quote missed around variable in ngIf condition.

```
<div *ngIf=!loaded" id="loader "> </div>
```

to

```
<div *ngIf="!loaded" id="loader "> </div>
```

Hope this may help to someone.

Answer (score 1):

The problem for me was that I had **declared the component into two different modules**.

Make sure that you declare your components only in one module.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, the way I fixed it to just debug it step by step to find out the root cause, normally its occure if you did not use the correct selector name in your html file which binds in the typescript file(.ts).

the second thing which you need to check in the templateURL files, try to use string interpolation rather than (tabtick with $ for variables). e-g use this {{ title }} if variable name is title. because as its a Ng Main module so whereever it will fail to compile it witll hit the same error.

but in the error you can see "its not a directive", so problem in the selector which you used in html is not matching with the ones used in ts file.

Answer (score 0):

all the above answers did not work for me. I deleted the component and used cli to generate it anew, I generated it slightly renamed.

Answer (score 0):

Try `ng serve`. The error should be resolved. If not, `npm i` it once.

Answer (score 0):

The following build command has fixed the issue for me in an ionic framework application

```
ionic cordova build android
```

Answer (score 0):

Well for my case this line here was causing all that

```js
this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case have some silent error in component import statement :

my shorthand path not working :

```
import { PageLabelsConfig } from '@core/_interfaces/page-labels.interface';
```

I changed it as below then works fine

```
 import { PageLabelsConfig } from '../../../../core/_interfaces/page-labels.interface';
```

shorthand  path detail : https://medium.com/@aleksanderkolata/angular-tips-01-get-rid-of-long-relative-import-paths-398c5926ecd4

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message, but traced the issue down to my app.module.ts  In this case I was registering a service as a Provider, and had, out of habit declared it in both @NgModule declarations and providers.  removing it from declarations fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the other answers, but this error is caused by calling the modules you want to load in the declaration part of the AppModule. Modules must be called in import section

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).