# Error: src/app/app.module.ts:18:5 - error NG6001:

Tags: angular

**This is EmployeeCountComponent it is declared in AppMpdule Declaration Array successfully and i am using this as a nested component in Employee-listComponent
I wanted to pass the Employee-listComponent data to the three properties declared in the EmployeeCountComponent i.e from Employee-listComponent  to EmployeeCountComponent  for that I have added Input decorators to EmployeeCount Class as it is getting input data from Employee-listComponent**

but i am encountering the following error

The class 'EmployeeCountComponent' is listed in the declarations of the
NgModule 'AppModule', but is not a directive, a component, or a pipe. Either remove it from the NgModule's declarations, or add an appropriate Angular decorator

```
 EmployeeCountComponent
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

src/app/employee-count/employee-count.component.ts:10:14
10 export class EmployeeCountComponent implements OnInit
{
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
'EmployeeCountComponent' is declared here.

Error: src/app/employee-count/employee-count.component.ts:21:15 - error NG2003: No suitable injection token for parameter
'all' of class 'EmployeeCountComponent'.
Consider using the @Inject decorator to specify an injection token.

21   constructor(all:number, male:number, female:number)  {
~~~

src/app/employee-count/employee-count.component.ts:21:19
21   constructor(all:number, male:number, female:number)  {
~~~~~~
This type is not supported as injection token.

**1.EmployeeCountComponent**

[EmployeeCountComponent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZKo4.png)

**2. EmployeeeListComponent**
[EmployeeeListComponent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcz0w.png)

Comment: Did the solution I provided worked?

Answer (score 0):

You have to run npm install when creating new components. Hot reload doesn't seem to be able to add the component.

You can check the same [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61308517/angular-compile-error-ng6001-the-class-is-listed-in-the-declarations-of-the-ng)

You can also `ng serve`

Answer (score 0):

### Remove the arguments to the employee-count.component.ts constructor

```
export class EmployeeCountComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input()
    all: number;
    @Input()
    male: number;
    @Input()
    female: number;

    constructor(){
      //remove the arguments
    }
    ngOnInit():void{

    }
}
```

#### and if you haven't already, set the inputs for all, male and female in employee-list.component.html

```
<app-employee-count [all]="countAllEmployees" [male]="countMaleEmployees" [female]="countFemaleEmployees"></app-employee-count>
```

#### Explanation

If you're constructing the class with html, e.g. by adding `<app-employee-count></app-employee-count>`, you can't pass it any arguments to the constructor. The constructor for a component is for [dependancy injection](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services#dependency-injection-di), e.g. adding services.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if i remove the parameters in the constructor i am getting the following error ---> Property 'Female' has no initializerty 'Female' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor      and if i initialize them with some random values, the values are not fetched properly.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the parameters which you have used in the parameters of the constructor.

If you want to pass data from child component (EmployeeCountComponent) to parent component(EmployeelistComponent ) then you have to use @output and EventEmitter. It helps to pass the data from the EmployeeCountComponent to EmployeelistComponent

Refer this link : https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs

Comment: I have added the Input decorators correctly but the error is like this --->The class 'EmployeeCountComponent' is listed in the declarations of the NgModule 'AppModule', but is not a directive, a component, or a pipe. Either remove it from the NgModule's declarations, or add an appropriate Angular decorator