# The class 'AppComponent' is listed in the declarations of the NgModule 'AppModule', but is not a directive, a component, or a pipe

Tags: angular

This is not a repeat of this: [Angular Compile Error: NG6001: The class is listed in the declarations of the NgModule 'AppModule', but is not a directive, a component, or a pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61308517/angular-compile-error-ng6001-the-class-is-listed-in-the-declarations-of-the-ng).

 I am trying to make a blog application but as in my app.modules.ts vs code shows this error:

```
The class 'AppComponent' is listed in the declarations of the NgModule 'AppModule', but 
is not a directive, a component, or a pipe. Either remove it from the NgModule's 
declarations, or add an appropriate Angular decorator
```

I am at loss as what this means. Firebase version is 8.2.6

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { provideFirebaseApp, initializeApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { getFirestore, provideFirestore, enableIndexedDbPersistence } from         '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { AngularFireModule } from "@angular/fire/compat";
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { articleComponent } from './article/article.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { TimelineComponent } from './timeline/timeline.component';
import { MatSlideToggleModule } from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AuthInterceptor } from "./services/auth.interceptor";
import { AllarticlesComponent } from './allarticles/allarticles.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { LostComponent } from './lost/lost.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    articleComponent,
    TimelineComponent,
    AllarticlesComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    LostComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
  ],
  providers: [
   
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Is your AppComponent decorated with @Component ?

Comment: yes my AppComponent is decorated with @Component

Comment: Can you post its code pls?

Comment: Sometimes this error appears when any other component or module contains errors. Try to comment all your declarations and imports, then uncomment one by one to know wich one is broken.